# Concurrent modification when next() has exhausted elements

Tags: java, iterator, concurrentmodification, nosuchelementexception

Been reading up on [Iterators](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~iris/se/12/latestSpec/api/java.base/java/util/Iterator.html) recently. Suppose that we want to build a *fail-fast* Iterator for a given container class. At some point in time, the following code has executed;

```
Iterator<Object> it = myContainer.iterator();
while(it.hasNext())
    System.out.println(it.next());
```

Then, we perform a modification on `myContainer`, using, say, a method called `remove(int index`):

```
myContainer.remove(2);      // Assume at least 3 elements contained
```

If `it.next()` is called *now*, and based on the official docs, should we throw an instance of `ConcurrentModificationException`, or `NoSuchElementException`? Perhaps more importantly, is this in any way inferrable from the official docs?

Comment: Please explain it clearly, It is not clear. what you are trying to do here.

Comment: I'm trying to find out which of the two `Exception`s *should* be thrown by somebody who wants to implement a _fail-fast_ `Iterator` class for a given container, like a stack, a list, a priority queue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`. A `NoSuchElementException` indicates there are no more elements in the iterator. When you encounter a concurrent modification, it always overrules the NoSuchElementException. At least that how the `Arraylist`and `LinkedList` are doing it.